# sys_platform is not defined x64 Windows

Tags: python, pip

This has been bugging me for a little while. I recently upgraded to x64 Python, and I started getting this error (example pip install).

```
C:\Users\<uname>\distribute-0.6.35>pip install python-qt
Collecting python-qt
  Downloading python-qt-0.50.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: python-qt
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for python-qt
  Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\<uname>\\appdata\\local\\t
emp\\pip-build-vonat7\\python-qt\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bd
ist_wheel -d c:\users\<uname>\appdata\local\temp\tmpghy5gtpip-wheel-:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "c:\users\<uname>\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-vonat7\python-qt\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
      packages=['Qt'],
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 137, in setup
      ok = dist.parse_command_line()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 232, in parse_command_line
      result = _Distribution.parse_command_line(self)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 467, in parse_command_line
      args = self._parse_command_opts(parser, args)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 558, in _parse_command_opts
      nargs = _Distribution._parse_command_opts(self, parser, args)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 523, in _parse_command_opts
      cmd_class = self.get_command_class(command)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 362, in get_command_class
      ep.require(installer=self.fetch_build_egg)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2027, in require
      working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer))
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2237, in requires
      dm = self._dep_map
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2466, in _dep_map
      self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2499, in _compute_dependencies
      common = frozenset(reqs_for_extra(None))
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2496, in reqs_for_extra
      if req.marker_fn(override={'extra':extra}):
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg\_markerlib\markers.py", line 109, in marker_fn
      return eval(compiled_marker, environment)
    File "<environment marker>", line 1, in <module>
  NameError: name 'sys_platform' is not defined

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for python-qt
Failed to build python-qt
Installing collected packages: python-qt
  Running setup.py install for python-qt
Successfully installed python-qt-0.50
```

The package was installed fine, but I cannot build wheels. I tried re-installing distribute manually by downloading a zip and running `python setup.py install`. That installed wonderfuly, without a hitch. But I still have the above problem.

How can I re-define sys_platform?

Alright, I rolled back to x86 good ole 32 bit Python, and I still have the problem. This is really concerning, because I cannot reset this after re-installing. I looked at [markerlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/markerlib/0.4), which looks promising, but I don't know how to use it safely. Currently I am unable to install pretty much *anything* from PyPI, so I am giving points to increase interest.

Any help? I really want to be able to use PyPI again.

**I chose the selected answer as it is the *most likely* to solve the problem. I myself have moved back to x86 Python, so I cannot test this myself. Therefore, I encourage future visitors to try this answer, but I have not myself been able to test it.**

Comment: Any luck with the problem??

Comment: No, but actually, could you post the following in your answer please? `Note from the OP: I chose this question as it is the _most likely_ to solve the problem. I myself have moved back to x86 Python, so I cannot test this myself. Therefore, I encourage future visitors to try this answer, but I have not myself been able to test it.` (Thanks @CRAKC if you post this)

Comment: well i would recommend that you do that. Post it as a comment to my answer. If I add this to my answer, it would just make no sense because you are the one who has accepted the answer and I am the one who has posted the answer. I think you understand. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Might be a bug. Check out: https://bugs.python.org/
2. You can manually check the markers.py file and try to fix it. I think there would a reference to `sys_platform` that has to be changed to `sys.platform`
3. Regarding markerlib, you can try this out-

   ```
   import markerlib
   marker = markerlib.compile("sys.platform == 'win32'")
   marker(environment=markerlib.default_environment(), override={'sys.platform':'win32'})
   ```

Comment: Can somebody share which step is the actual answer? 1, 2, or 3? Thanks!

Comment: @DominicJodoin try all of them. Please read this (posted by the asker) **Note from the OP: I chose this question as it is the _most likely_ to solve the problem. I myself have moved back to x86 Python, so I cannot test this myself. Therefore, I encourage future visitors to try this answer, but I have not myself been able to test it.**

Answer (score 4):

To fix this error, I found that installing the 0.7.3 version of distribute fixed this. I had also upgraded setuptools and pip along the way (so they may be needed as well), but after upgrading distribute this error finally went away.

Comment: Nope. I just re-installed distribute form the PyPi site to no avail. I also updated setuptools and pip. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 4):

Try removing pip and distribute and setuptools, and then manually install pip using [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) .

Then , download setuptools from [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-17.1.1.zip#md5=363668feaa5137a8c6d3c94f4e27949e) , extract -> go inside the extracted folder in command prompt and do `python setup.py install`

Then , download distribute from [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.7.3.zip#md5=c6c59594a7b180af57af8a0cc0cf5b4a) , extract -> go inside the extracted folder in command prompt and do `python setup.py install`

Comment: I of course did this as my first step, but it didn't help at all. I just tried it again, and when I tried `python setup.py install` for distribute, it failed with `error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\<uname>\\Downloads\\distribute-0.7.3\\setuptools\\cli-32.exe'`, which isn't in the specified folder (manually checked). So no, this didn't help. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today myself, though on OSX. I had run `--upgrade` as well as trying to uninstall and reinstall it completely.

Eventually, though I went into my site packages, and saw a "correct" version of `setuptools` (18.1) AS WELL as an older *lingering* version of it (completely separate version 15.1 of it). Removing it all and reinstalling `setuptools` fresh fixed it for me.

Hopefully this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I had an old verison of distribute, which didn't correctly resolve dependencies. It was fixed with

```
C:\Users\cshucks>pip install --upgrade distribute
Collecting distribute
  Downloading distribute-0.7.3.zip (145kB)
    100% |################################| 147kB 375kB/s
Collecting setuptools>=0.7 (from distribute)
  Downloading setuptools-19.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (463kB)
    100% |################################| 466kB 440kB/s
Installing collected packages: setuptools, distribute
  Found existing installation: setuptools 16.0
    Uninstalling setuptools-16.0:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-16.0
  Found existing installation: distribute 0.6.49
    Uninstalling distribute-0.6.49:
      Successfully uninstalled distribute-0.6.49
  Running setup.py install for distribute
Successfully installed distribute-0.7.3 setuptools-19.2
```